# В Xcode не отображается редактор сцены

Tags: ios, xcode

На моем Hackintosh возникла проблема с Xcode SceneKit editor: не отображается редактор сцен. В остальном программа работает отлично, как и сама система. Возможно, проблема в OpenGL или других драйверах?

[image: Снимок экрана]

Comment: Какая видокарта у Вас?

Comment: @VAndrJ NVIDIA 970 4Gb

Comment: Некислая карточка для хакинтоша :) QE/CI работает?

Comment: @VAndrJ Да, работает. Также заметил, что программа вылетает при попытке открытия SpriteKit Scene (.sks) файлов. На форумах прочитал, что Xcode (Scene editor) на хакинтошах работает только с iGPU.. Сомнительное удовольствие обладать такой картой, которую по сути и не использовать в разработке.. :)